# mysql gem not working on Leopard

Tags: mysql, ruby

I keep getting this error when including

require "mysql"

in my  programs

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin9.0/mysql.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin9.0/mysql.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin9.0/mysql.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin9.0/mysql.bundle
    from connect.rb:13
```

and I've noticed that this library isn't actually there... This is what I get when I list the directory

```
3536 libmysqlclient.18.dylib*        4 libmysqlclient_r.dylib@
  8660 libmysqlclient.a            53888 libmysqld-debug.a
     4 libmysqlclient.dylib@       50496 libmysqld.a
     4 libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib@      8 libmysqlservices.a
     4 libmysqlclient_r.a@             0 plugin/
```

I am trying to install it with the following command, but it still doesn't work:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- \
> --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib \
> --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table

No definition for field_def

No definition for field_type

No definition for field_length

No definition for field_max_length

No definition for field_flags

No definition for field_decimals

No definition for time_inspect

No definition for time_to_s

No definition for time_get_year

No definition for time_get_month

No definition for time_get_day

No definition for time_get_hour

No definition for time_get_minute

No definition for time_get_second

No definition for time_get_neg

No definition for time_get_second_part

No definition for time_set_year

No definition for time_set_month

No definition for time_set_day

No definition for time_set_hour

No definition for time_set_minute

No definition for time_set_second

No definition for time_set_neg

No definition for time_set_second_part

No definition for time_equal

No definition for error_errno

No definition for error_sqlstate
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table

No definition for field_def

No definition for field_type

No definition for field_length

No definition for field_max_length

No definition for field_flags

No definition for field_decimals

No definition for time_inspect

No definition for time_to_s

No definition for time_get_year

No definition for time_get_month

No definition for time_get_day

No definition for time_get_hour

No definition for time_get_minute

No definition for time_get_second

No definition for time_get_neg

No definition for time_get_second_part

No definition for time_set_year

No definition for time_set_month

No definition for time_set_day

No definition for time_set_hour

No definition for time_set_minute

No definition for time_set_second

No definition for time_set_neg

No definition for time_set_second_part

No definition for time_equal

No definition for error_errno

No definition for error_sqlstate
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I never found an answer. After hours of headaches I finally installed [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

- It's super easy to use
- It intalls everything in a clean,
  separated folder, so you can always
  fall back on the default Apple version.
- It's quite up to date (it includes ruby 1.9)

Comment: Good idea. I ended up using JRuby and the jdbc mysql driver instead, I've been looking for a reason to install macports..

Comment: I installed MacPorts. And now? what i should do? If i try to install gem mysql still happen the same. Thanks